# Remove ' in array Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

In my controller I have:

```
@cabs_city = VwVolsCabs.all

@cabs_city = @cabs_city.each { |s| s.gsub! /[^[:alnum:]]/, '' }
```

View:

```
<% @cabs_city.each do |s| %>
    <%= s.cab_name %>
<% end %>
```

But I have this error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `gsub!' for #<VwVolsCabs:0x000000089e8dd0>):
```

Comment: Looks like there's something wrong in your controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller:

```
@cabs_city = VwVolsCabs.all
@cabs_city.each { |s| s.cab_name.gsub! /[^[:alnum:]]/, '' }
```

Comment: You can get rid of the second `@cabs_city = `, you don't need to assign it back to the same variable again

Comment: @Gareth, Thkank you for comment. That was from original code. I updated the code.